# How to get subcategory posts in wordpress

Tags: php, wordpress, post

I have a Wordpress question. I have main category and subcategories. Subcategories have several posts. Below structure:

Infoguide(Main Category)

- News (sub-category)

  - Post1(sub-category post)
  - Post2(sub-category post)
  - Post3(sub-category post)
- Resourses (sub-category)

  - Post1(sub-category post)
  - Post2(sub-category post)
- Books (sub-category)

  - Post1(sub-category post)
  - Post2(sub-category post)

I can get subcategories from current category by below code

```
<?php
$subcategories = get_categories('&child_of=31&hide_empty&orderby=title&order=ASC');
echo '<ul class="styleUl">';
foreach ($subcategories as $subcategory) {
    echo sprintf('
        <li class="col-lg-4 col-md-4 col-sm-6 col-xs-12">
            <a class="catImg" href="%s"">%s</a>
        </li>
    ', get_category_link($subcategory->term_id), apply_filters('get_term', $subcategory->name));
}
echo '</ul>';
?>
```

This worked for me. But I can't figure out by next task which is get  subcategory posts by clicking. How to solve this? Please help me.

Comment: You mean you need all posts from a subcategory by clicking sucategory anchor ?

Comment: Yes, you are right @Poria

Comment: create a page with different template to show the posts by subcategory id and send the id of subcategory in the link to that page.

Comment: Thank you for quick reply @Poria, is it single.php or archive.php? Can you  clearify your answer?  How wordpress knows it is template of news subcategory? Thank you in advance

Comment: 1) Create a template by copying page.php or any other template
2) then add a page and assign the new template to that page. 
3) You will be sending id of subcategory from your link to the new page with new template like mynew_template.php?subcategory=5 and then 
4) on the template file get it from $_GET['sucategory']; then fetch the posts under it and display them

Comment: Got it, thank you @Poria

Comment: Posting it as answer to help others, please accept the answer

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this

1) Create a template by copying page.php or any other template

2) then add a page and assign the new template to that page.

3) You will be sending id of subcategory from your link to the new page with new template like mynew_template.php?subcategory=5 and then

4) on the template file get it from $_GET['sucategory']; then fetch the posts under it and display them

Hope these instructions help !

Comment: I did 1) and 2) instructions. I need help for 3rd instruction. How can I send to each page-template.php in above loop, for example, <a class="catImg" href="%s"">%s</a>. Please, give me a example. Thank you.

Comment: You need to send every subcategory link to single page template that you created to display the subcategory posts with different subcategory ids
What is the output of your loop, show me the html

Comment: <ul>
 <li class="col-lg-4 col-md-4 col-sm-6 col-xs-12">
  <a class="catImg" href="http://domen.com/category/infoguide/subcategory/">Some text</a>
 </li>

 <li class="col-lg-4 col-md-4 col-sm-6 col-xs-12">
  <a class="catImg" href="http://domen.com/category/infoguide/subcategory2/">Some text</a>
 </li>

</ul>

Comment: Now on the page infoguide , you are getting the subcategory slug as parameter like subcategory, subcategory2, why not pass id instead like

foreach ($subcategories as $subcategory) {
    echo '<li class="col-lg-4 col-md-4 col-sm-6 col-xs-12"><a class="catImg" href="your_new_template_page_slug?subcategory='.$subcat->cat_ID.'">'.$subcat->cat_name.'</a></li>';
}